# Legend about inconsistent person

Tags: myth-identification, mythohistory

Is there a myth or a legend about some inconsistent person? Some young and ambitious man, who want a lot of fame and fortune, but don't know exactly how to reach that. Who demonstrates in his actions and deeds aspiration to reach the target, but have no enough means for that, knowledge and experience.

**OR**

Is there a myth or a legend, which describes personal emotional, mental and finally physical tragedy of the man, who haven't compared his wishes with reality and finally reached the hell?

---

I am looking for a myth or a legend representing that idea, but only found [The Tale of the Fisherman and the Fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tale_of_the_Fisherman_and_the_Fish)

Comment: Hmm, these descriptions doesn't really strike me as being inconsistent per se. Are you looking for examples of someone dreaming too big, or is this a specific story you're trying to identify?